# What is the native resolution for this game?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

The game on launch gives me a number of resolution options, but it seems that none of them actually matches the in-game artwork. This leads to really ugly results. [720×576](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOTij.jpg) is perhaps the closest I can get to something that isn't *too* awful, but it's still pretty bad (look at the width of the stems of the "Edition" word.) [1152×864](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr0wx.jpg) is still off and [1176×664](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK7Ii.jpg) is *almost* tolerable.

What *is* however the perfect resolution (and multiples thereof) to play this game at and how can I set it if it isn't one of the defaults? (Is there one at all?)

Comment: Many tries later, it seems that [1440×900](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Ptq.jpg) is the smallest least offensive built-in option, but [text is still pretty ugly.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LYkxV.jpg)

Comment: 1024x768 looks good for me